# How to get real time update of firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch a single string from my firebase database. Although I don't see any error but when I change the data, it's not reflected. I just want to store a string online in firebase and then retrieve it later.
I'm doing this for an android app. Here's the code of MainActivity. Please tell where am I going wrong.

```
package sadboy.firebase;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

[public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {][1]

private TextView title;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("hey");
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("new_title").setValue("Realtime Database");
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("new_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.e("Hey", appTitle);
            title.setText(appTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Hey", "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
        }
    });


}
}
```

[image]

Find the project here : 
https://github.com/heysadboy/Firebase-Sample

Comment: https://github.com/heysadboy/Firebase-Sample here is the complete project that I'm trying to do.

Comment: is the data being displayed when you are opening your app (i.e. for the first time)? also image of your database is not displayed in your question. Upload it on imgur and share the link later someone with higher rep will edit it for you.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay please check my github repo. The image is there in the readme.md. I have low credits so I can't add image here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this approach:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView title;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference();

        mFirebaseDatabase.child("new_title").setValue("Realtime Database");
        mFirebaseDatabase.child("new_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                Log.e("Hey", appTitle);
                title.setText(appTitle);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.e("Hey", "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I made slight changes to your layout just to make it easier to test the codes. Here are the changes I made:

**activity_main.xml**

I added an EditText and Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="sadboy.firebase.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="SEND" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

Once the Send Button's clicked, I took the String from EditText and store it as `new_title` value at your Firebase Database, while listen to the changes made at `new_title` and show the value at TextView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView title;
    private EditText etInput;
    private Button btSend;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        etInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input);
        btSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_send);

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        btSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String valuetoSend = etInput.getText().toString();
                mFirebaseDatabase.child("new_title").setValue(valuetoSend);
            }
        });

        mFirebaseDatabase.child("new_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                title.setText(appTitle);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.e("Hey", "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for suggestion But unfortunately doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Do check it on github to see other files maybe.

Comment: @VarunKumar what did you mean by not working? Did `title` TextView not show "Realtime Database" string? Because i've already tried it and it worked well. I've updated `new_title` value in your Database you might check it (sorry to use your database, I can use it because you give your google_services.json file on github)

Comment: @JaniceKartika ; good answer, I think you could use the database without having the `google_services.json` file too (just by knowing the database url as read and write permissions are true). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JaniceKartika Hi thanks. Your answer is working. I saw my database and the field was changed to "its working" but when I send it from my phone I don't see the change in the database. What could be the reason? Did you also added anything else, maybe dependencies. I guess I have problem with them maybe.

Comment: It would be great if you could send me the link of the project you made. You can use my database, it's ok.

Comment: Here you go @VarunKumar https://github.com/JaniceKartika/firebase-example

Comment: Thank you so much @JaniceKartika . I'm really very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ckecked your database rules on firebase console?
Change them like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. They look like that.

Comment: See it on github if something is wrong with my project.

Comment: Hi, try it like this:
 mFirebaseInstance.child("new_title").setValue("Realtime Database");
    mFirebaseInstance.child("new_title").addValueEventListener(....

Comment: Not working. You can fork from github and try if you want.